# how to sort a list of strings alphabetically in java?

Tags: java

Hie.

I am a Java beginner. I need to sort a String of names alphabetically. 
i have a class that reads from a text file and writes the sorted file which filters by age(less than 18) but i need it to filter alphabetically, below is my implementation. Its working fine without filter by name.

```
        public class PatientFileProcessor {

            public void process(File source, File target) {

                System.out.println("source"+source.getAbsolutePath());
                System.out.println("target"+target.getAbsolutePath()); 

                try {
                    writefile(target, filterbyAge(readfile(source)));
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(PatientFileProcessor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

            public List<Patient> readfile(File source) throws Exception {
                List<Patient> patients = new ArrayList();
                BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(source));
                String s = bf.readLine();// ignore first line
                while ((s = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] split = s.split("\\|");
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
                    System.out.println(s+"       "+split[0]+"       "+split[1]+"       "+split[2]);
                    Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM").parse(split[2]);
                    patients.add(new Patient(split[0], split[1], d));
                }
                return patients;
            }

            public void writefile(File target, List<Patient> sorted) throws Exception {

                BufferedWriter pw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(target));
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/dd/MM");

                for (Iterator<Patient> it = sorted.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                    Patient p = it.next();


                    pw.append(p.getName() + "|" + p.getGender() + "|" + df.format(p.getDob()));
                    pw.newLine();
                }
                pw.flush();
            }

            public List<Patient> filterbyAge(List<Patient> ps) {
                List<Patient> sorted = new ArrayList();
                for (Iterator<Patient> it = ps.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                    Patient s = it.next();
                    if (calcAge(s.getDob()) > 18) {
                        sorted.add(s);
                    }

                }
                return sorted;
            }


            public int calcAge(Date d) {
                Date today = new Date();
                long m = today.getTime() - d.getTime();
                return (int) (m / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25));
            }

            }
```

Patient:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Patient {
    private String name;
    private String gender;
    private Date dob;

    public Patient() {
    }

    public Patient(String name, String gender, Date dob) {
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }
}
```

how do i go about it?

Comment: you can't "filter alphabetically", you have to sort alphabetically.

Comment: You ask about sorting a list of strings, but there is no list of strings in your code.  Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: yes Stephen you right , my error its a list of objects

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that those are Strings, use the convenient static method [`sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)…

```
 java.util.Collections.sort(patients)
```

Comment: hie my Patient object looks like this:public class Patient {

 private String name;
 private String gender;
 private Date dob;

 public Patient() {
 }

 public Patient(String name, String gender, Date dob) {
  this.name = name;
  this.gender = gender;
  this.dob = dob;
 }

 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }

 public String getGender() {
  return gender;
 }

 public void setGender(String gender) {
  this.gender = gender;
 }

 public Date getDob() {
  return dob;
 }

Comment: so on sort() it complains that it cant you the void method(sort)

Comment: @Pami it says it can't fnd the method sort? most likely, you'll need to implement Comparable or something similar to get this to work. do you know how to work with interfaces? Also: don't post the code for an entire class in a comment, it's unreadable

Answer (score 0):

For Strings this would work:
arrayList.sort((p1, p2) -> p1.compareTo(p2)); (Java 8)

Comment: for Strings, yes, but they are not Strings

Comment: You can try this:
patientList
  .stream()
  .sorted((object1, object2) -> object1.getName().compareTo(object2.getName()));

Comment: this is the method i created::   public List<Patient>SortPatients(List<Patient>mYPatients){
     List<Patient>patientList = new ArrayList();
     
     Collections.sort(patientList, Comparator.comparing(Patient::getName));
  return patientList;
    } but i dont know where to put it

Comment: this is my write method but it wont take patientList as a paramtere::  public void writefile(File target, List<Patient> sorted,List<Patient> patientList) {

        BufferedWriter pw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(target));
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/dd/MM");
        
        for (Iterator<Patient> it = sorted.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Patient p = it.next();
           
            
            pw.append(p.getName() + "|" + p.getGender() + "|" + df.format(p.getDob()));
            pw.newLine();
        }
            }

Comment: Add this method:
public List<Patient> sortByName(List<Patient> ps) {
  ps.sort(Comparator.comparing(Patient::getName,
    Comparator.comparing((String s) -> !s.equals("None")).thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
  return ps;
 }  and call the above method from process method : public void process(File source, File target) {

  System.out.println("source" + source.getAbsolutePath());
  System.out.println("target" + target.getAbsolutePath());

  try {
    writefile(target, sortByName(filterbyAge(readfile(source))));
  } catch (Exception ex) {
  }
 }

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is you can implement the `Comparable` interface in your `Patient` and override the `compareTo` method. In that way, when the sort method of Collections is called, it will use the your compareTo method for comparison.